# NxN array print with conditions

Tags: java, arrays

this is a simple code example i did, but why doesn'it work? it says "Exception in thread "main" "  , how can i resolve?

`

```
public class Matrice {
    public static void Carica(final int N){
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
            for(int j=0;i<N;j++) {
                if ((i%j==0) || (j%i==0))
                    System.out.println("1");
                else
                    System.out.println("0");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int x=10;
        Carica(x);
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Many many languages support arrays. You need to tag the language (which I have done for you).

Comment: Your second for loop is incorrect: for(int j=0;i<N;j++)

Comment: When 'j' is zero, `i%j` will produce "/ by zero" exception.

Answer (score 0):

In `i%j==0`:

`j` was initialized to `0` in `for(int j=0;i<N;j++) {`.

```
i % 0
```

Will throw divide by zero exception.

Comment: thank you so much, i fixed :), but now program doesn't work, it prints all "1" and not "0"  (input is x=3 , so 3x3 )

Comment: You are welcome :). Can you paste here in comments your edited version?